# problems with java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, keystore, keytool

I have problem with my program. I would like to have access to keystore, user give a pass and path. my code:

```
public class cipher_player {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{    

        KeyStore klucz = KeyStore.getInstance("JCEKS");

        Console konsola = System.console();
        char passwordArray[] = konsola.readPassword("Password: ");

        java.io.FileInputStream plik_keystore = null;

        try{
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Path to keystore: ");
            String pathArray = konsola.readLine();
            System.out.print(pathArray);
            plik_keystore = new java.io.FileInputStream(pathArray);
            klucz.load(plik_keystore, passwordArray);
            if(plik_keystore != null){
                plik_keystore.close();
            }
            scanner.close();

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Keystore not found");
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
}
```

and when I run it display this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at crypto3.cipher_player.main(cipher_player.java:47)
```

its line with `char passwordArray[] = konsola.readPassword("Password: ");`

I don't have idea how solve this problem.

Comment: konsola is null -- look back into your program to see why. Your system may not allow a console. Not every system does.

Comment: Are you running this code via IDE (Eclipse, NetBeans, IntelliJ)? If so then even if your system does support Console then if your code is run via `javaw.exe` (option without console, default in IDEs) you will also get null as result of `System.console()`.

Comment: There's only one thing in that line that could be null and causing your problem -- `konsola`.

Answer (score 1):

Your System object won't return a valid Console object. Not all allow for this.

As per the System API:

> Returns the unique Console object associated with the current Java virtual machine, **if any**.
>   Returns:
>             The system console, if any, **otherwise null**.
>   `<emphasis mine>`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to run the application from IDE - that's why `System.console()` returns null. Try running the app from the command line.